# How to find µ (Gravitational constant mass product) with PlanetData?

Tags: curated-data, astronomy

I would like to use [`PlanetData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanetData.html) to get `µ`, the product of the Gravitational constant `G` and a planet's mass `m`.

This property is listed in the documentation (Mathematica v10.1.0.0) for [`PlanetData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanetData.html) as the property `"GravitationalConstantMassProduct"`.

Unfortunately, the property appears unknown upon execution:

```
PlanetData["Earth", "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"]
```

> Missing["UnknownProperty", {"Planet", 
>     "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"}]

In addition, the property also does not appear to be in the list of properties when queried as follows:

```
PlanetData["Properties"]
```

Given that this is a highly useful constant (known to far greater accuracy than a planet's mass FWIW), I'd like to know what has happened to it.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mars+Gravitational+Constant++mass+product

Comment: To expand on @belisarius comment - it seems to be a recurring feature of Wolframs Curated Data that the Mathematica version of it tends to be the poor relation of the similar dataset held in W|A.  There are similar issues with `CountryData`

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why we don't just multiply `EntityProperty["Planet", "Mass"]` by `Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]`: we can measure $\mu=MG$ with *much* greater accuracy (~9 decimal places) than we can measure $G$, or by extension, $M$ (~4 decimal places).

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, thank you; this is exactly the reason I'd prefer to have µ.

Answer (score 3):

```
WolframAlpha["mars Gravitational Constant  mass product", {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}]
```

> 4.28*10^13

or

```
WolframAlpha["mars Gravitational Constant  mass product", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

> Quantity[4.28*10^13, ("Meters")^3/("Seconds")^2]

Comment: I guess, WA or example data isn't going to be too useful here. I couldn't force WA to give answers to more than two decimal places.

Comment: Perhaps data accuracy doesn't warrant more digits. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) has two more digits for Mars.